# How to send an object file .o via ssl and socket

Tags: c, ssl, file-io, send

I need to send an object file from my client to the server program.
I tried reading the file, storing it into a buffer, sent the buffer over the ssl and wrote to a file in the server program. 
This did not work for .o files.  This was the out put ELF.

This is some of my code

Read file

```
void readFile(char filename[])  
{
    FILE        *input_file;
    char        line[BUFSIZ];

    input_file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(input_file == NULL){
        printf("cannot open input_file '%s'\n", filename );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

while (fgets(line,sizeof line, input_file) != NULL) {

    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(line); i++){
        current_file[i] = line[i];
    }   
}}
```

Client sends the file

```
    readFile(filename);
    ctx = InitCTX();  
    server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum));  
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */  
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */  
    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL )   /* perform the connection */  
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);  
    else  
    {   

        printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));  
        ShowCerts(ssl);        /* get any certs */  
        SSL_write(ssl, current_file, strlen(current_file));
```

Is it possible to read object file, and then store it in a buffer?

Is there other methods to send these file?

Comment: First of all, object files are binary, and should be opened with the `b` flag to `fopen`. Secondly you can not use `fgets` when reading binary files, since that function interprets the data as text and will fail when it contains the binary data values 0 (used for string termination) or 10 (which is the newline character, and binary files don't have lines) and probably other values as well. Use `fread` to read the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing 'special' about a .o file, it's simply a series of bytes stored on disc, with a filename and extension assigned to it.

My guess would be that you need to handle the file differently from what you have there, as it's going to be binary data. It won't have the 'usual' concept of lines that you're currently reading in.

I'd have a look at the following:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/c-howto-read-binary-file-into-buffer-172985/

Try reading then writing your file locally first to check whether it's being corrupted in transit or in the local I/O routines?

Comment: Cheers guys for good replys.. Here is a -> [link](http://www.sourcepod.com/tyluao20-5853) to a working read and write function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code for buffering binary files like the "object" ones. Checks and pointers maintenance are not there for brevity sake.

```
 FILE *file;
 char *buffer;
 unsigned long len;
 unsigned char buffer*;
 //open in binary mode
 file = fopen(name, "rb");
 //check file size
 fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
 len = ftell(file);
 fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
 //allocate buffer accordingly
 buffer = (unsigned char *) calloc (1, fileLen + 1); //1 byte for the terminator
 //Store into buffer
 fread(buffer, len, 1, file);
```